# Filling an HTML Table with Data from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've tried all day to get this stupid page to work, and I can't figure it out. I'm trying to get info from a table to show up in a table in a php file.

```
if (!mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password))
  die("Connection failed: ");

if (!mysql_select_db($dbname))
  die("Can't select database");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT problem_id, machine_id, description FROM tbl_problem");

if (!$result)
{
  die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<table class='table table-hover'><tr><th>Problem ID</th><th>Machine Number</th><th>Problem Description</th><th>     </th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>" . $row['problem_id']. "</td><td>" . $row['machine_id']. "</td><td>" . $row['description']. "</td><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger'>Resolved?</button></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I've used several websites to try and get this to work, but nothing seems to be working. If syntax is really out of whack, it's because I'm modelling it after everything I've seen similar to what I'm trying to do.

What it should do, is if the table "tbl_problem" has data in it, display a table on the website that shows the Problem ID, Machine ID, and Description as well as a button to the right of that which allows you to delete the row from "tbl_problem" (the button is there as a placeholder right now, I don't have code for it to actually delete yet, but if someone wanted to point me in the right direction with that, I'd be much obliged!).

When I run it, I get no table, and instead see the following:

> Problem IDMachine NumberProblem Description "; while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { echo "" . $row['problem_id']. "" . $row['machine_id']. "" . $row['description']. ""; } echo "[The Resolved? button displays properly here]"; /*else { echo "There are no problems! :)"; }*/ ?>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of [mysql_fetch_row()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) to get this code working.

As `mysql_fetch_row()` fetches row as an array with numeric keys e.g. 0,1, 2,....

And `mysql_fetch_assoc()` fetches row as an array and its elements with associative keys e.g 'abc', 'xyz', ...

And in your code, you are expecting array and its elements with associative keys.

Hence, second option will work for you.

Comment: I did as you said, and currently, the only difference is that the outputted text now read mysql_fetch_assoc( instead. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing PHP source output in your browser window then it means your document was not executed as a PHP script, therefore either PHP is not installed or it's misconfigured (are you using `.php` as your filename extension and is your webserver configured to use PHP to process those files?)

Comment: The filename is .php, and it's for a university project, and the professor told us to use PHP, so I would assume it is set up for it.

Comment: @JaysenStoudt Create an empty `.php` script with just `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` in it and see if it executes and reports info about PHP or not.

Comment: I added "<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>"
In about 3 places in the code I have in the question, and see nothing anywhere. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @JaysenStoudt if you get a blank page then it means PHP is not configured on your webserver, speak to your professor/sysadmin.

Comment: Actually, I figured out the problem. And it's that I'm dumb. I was trying to access it by simply right clicking the PHP file and opening it. Rather than accessing it via the website... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what Programming Student's said: using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is a common practice. However, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is depreciated in newer versions of PHP.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['problem_id']."</td><td>".$row['machine_id']."</td></tr>";
}
```

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_assoc.asp) for an example of `mysqli` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:500px" >

    <thead style="background-color:#09C;color:#FFF">

    <tr>

        <th> Name </th>

        <th> Age </th>

    </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php

        $activities = mysqli_query($con,"select * from user where roleid = 1 order by active desc");

        while($activity = mysqli_fetch_array($activities))
        {

    ?>


        <tr>

            <td> <a href="<?php echo $editlink ?>" style="text-decoration:none"> <?php echo $activity['name'] ?> </a> </td>

            <td> <?php echo $activity['age'] ?> </td>

        </tr>

    <?php

        }

    ?>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main page try adding this code

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Name of Column 1
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name of Column 2
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Name of Column 3
                        </th>           
                    </tr>
                        <?php
                            Name::listName();
                            //$sql
                        ?>
```

And in your class (assumed that you have one) add this

```
<?php
class Name{
  public $yourcol1;
  public $yourcol2;
  public $yourcol3;

 public function __construct(){
    $this->yourcol1=''; //assumed all are strings
    $this->yourcol2='';
    $this->yourcol3='';
 }
public static function listName(){
    $qry="select * from tbl_yourtablename;";
    $cResult=mysql_query($qry);
    if($cResult){
        while($cRows=mysql_fetch_array($cResult)){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$cRows['yourcol1'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cRows['yourcol2'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$cRows['uourcol3'].'</td></tr>';
        }
    }else{
        ShowDbError();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps